# GET Request Works in Postman but not with RestTemplate - SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a request that is working fine when I try to send through postman.
I was trying to implement the same using code where I faced an error.

The code i am using -

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("client_id", clientid);
map.add("client_secret",clientsecret);

HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
logger.info(request.toString());

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(access_token_url)
                    .queryParam("grant_type", "client_credentials");

logger.info("URI -" + builder.toUriString());

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), 
   HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
logger.info("Response" + response.getBody());
```

The error I am getting is -

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized:
>   401 Unauthorized

But the same works in POSTMAN with the same details.

Something I want to specify

- The back-end API is not in my hands.
- The clientid, clientsecret, access_token_url are fetched from properties file and are correct I have cross checked them.
- It is a GET request with x-www-form-urlencoded data. I checked it multiple times it is not POST
- There is no Authorization such as Basic Auth as it is not set in POSTMAN itself
- Went through [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285338/httpclienterrorexception-401-unauthorized-basic-authentication) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240474/spring-resttemplate-gives-401-unauthorized-error-when-sending-with-authorization) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741220/spring-resttemplate-receives-401-unauthorized) nothing helped.

My main concern is I have never seen anywhere sending a GET request with method body, but it is working in POSTMAN and if it is working there why not in the code? Where I am going wrong?

EDIT - 1
Was marked duplicate with [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339753/rest-post-works-correctly-with-postman-but-exception-when-using-spring-resttempl) but its a different error code overall. The OP got `500 Internal Server Error` as he was giving wrong content type.

EDIT - 2 
DEBUG Output-

```
2019-07-31 14:53:05.208 DEBUG 3576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET ORIGINAL_URL?grant_type=client_credentials
2019-07-31 14:53:05.215 DEBUG 3576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2019-07-31 14:53:05.218 DEBUG 3576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{client_id=[CLIENTID], client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2019-07-31 14:53:06.976 DEBUG 3576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
2019-07-31 14:53:07.034 DEBUG 3576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/html', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/signed-exchange;v=b3, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [text/plain, */*, text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-07-31 14:53:07.035 DEBUG 3576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Nothing to write: null body
2019-07-31 14:53:07.039 DEBUG 3576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2019-07-31 14:53:07.108 DEBUG 3576 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/favicon.ico", parameters={}
2019-07-31 14:53:07.119 DEBUG 3576 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/], class path resource []]
2019-07-31 14:53:07.181 DEBUG 3576 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST POST works correctly with POSTMAN but exception when using Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339753/rest-post-works-correctly-with-postman-but-exception-when-using-spring-resttempl)

Comment: Have you logged the spring request to see if it matches your postman request? There is some usefull class like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses#33009822

Comment: can you show the postman curl for your request?

Comment: You are telling us one way works another doesn’t. You post the code for the one that doesn’t but you don’t post the call that works. Are we supposed to guess what your API looks like so we can fix your broken code?

Comment: Here is the curl that is wokring

`curl -X GET \
  'URL-OF-CLIENT?grant_type=client_credentials' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_secret=SECRET&client_id=ID'`

Comment: check if you have a client certificate configured in postman settigns

Comment: It is not @e.g78

Comment: export the postman collection as json and paste it, otherwise it is impossible to compare it with the resttemplate request

Comment: @e.g78 the postman is not with me. I cannot access it directly. But i can assure that everything in request template is as per the postman. Including all headers and predefined parameters, there is no typos or anything missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the same use case, we are using the below implementation.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
String token = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode((clientId + ":" + clientSecret).getBytes()));
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
logger.info(request.toString());
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(access_token_url).queryParam("grant_type", "client_credentials");
logger.info("URI -" + builder.toUriString());
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST,request, String.class);
logger.info("Response" + response.getBody());
```

this might help you.

Comment: That works!! Thanks. Could you please explain what was my error here?

Comment: 1. you were using GET, 2. you were trying to sent client Id and client secret as part of request where as we were sending them as part of Authorization Header

Answer (score 0):

i suspect the following. You are double encoding your url, change:

```
restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), 
    HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

to

```
restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), 
    HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

You can easy match your requests by enabling debug for spring web.

application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip. I tested your solution, still its not working. It is giving me same result as before

Comment: please post the debug output

Comment: Posted debug in OP

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue.  The problem turned out to be that there was a proxy required to access a URI outside the company. Postman had been configured to use the proxy.

Here's the code to fix this:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;

// Initialize the REST Template with a proxy.
private RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
    if(restTemplate==null) {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
    return restTemplate;
}
```

See // https://www.baeldung.com/java-resttemplate-proxy